Statistical comparison of treatment vs control when ratio is meaningful
I have a statistical problem that I am running into and I wonder if you are willing to help me out. I've done an experiment in which I have measured fluorescent signal (from a tagged protein) in plant leaves, and I'm trying to find out if a hormone treatment increases this signal compared to a control. I've done this experiment in 4 runs, with 3 equal leaf samples per plant (rep), but somehow the experimental conditions (solution age, machine, plant batch, etc.) have caused quite a large difference between the values obtained in each run. See some my data below; note that the control and treatment conditions are in fact different plants so the data is not paired:
run treatment signal rep
1 control 4.27 1
1 control 3.85 2
1 control 3.93 3
1 hormone 5.14 1
1 hormone 5.37 2
1 hormone 4.13 3
2 control 4.94 1
2 control 4.43 2
2 control 6.04 3
2 hormone 9.42 1
2 hormone 7.98 2
2 hormone 5.95 3
3 control 20.26 1
3 control 19.98 2
3 control 16.46 3
3 hormone 24.06 1
3 hormone 18.78 2
3 hormone 17.56 3
4 control 15.93 1
4 control 12.99 2
4 control 12.71 3
4 hormone 17.28 1
4 hormone 18.39 2
4 hormone 17.76 3

As you can see, the signal values in experimental run 1 & 2 differ greatly from 3 & 4. However, within runs, the hormone treatment seems to be consistently increasing the signal. We see very similar results for other data coming from these four experimental runs.
I want to make a statistical comparison between the two treatments, but simply performing a pairwise test is not going to be of much help. I can try to control for the variation in signal caused by the experimental runs by dividing the hormone values by the mean of the control values per run to get average ratios:
run treatment mean_signal
1 control 1.00
1 hormone 1.21
2 control 1.00
2 hormone 1.52
3 control 1.00
3 hormone 1.07
4 control 1.00
4 hormone 1.28

...but then I am comparing average ratios to the control... all with value 1.00 (so zero variation). It feels like I'm missing something, but I have no idea what. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is what I would try. Take the average signal for all control replicates from each run (as you have done). Then divide all treatment signals by the corresponding control average, to obtain ratios. Then you can simply do a 1-sample t-test on these "calibrated" ratios, and compare it to 1 (single sided test as you are trying to show that hormone increases the signal).
This is basically what you did, except that I kept the indivudual observations for the hormone replicates, for increased power. And that I now do not compare to the controls, as I already used them to "calibrate" the data for differences between the runs (or, viewed differently, I compare the treatment to teh average of the controls, which will be, by construction, 1).
Now, instead of ratios, you could also simply look at differences (diff between each hormone value and the mean of the corresponding control group), and run again a single-sided 1-sample t, this time against a 0 mean diff.
Now this is based on whether this "calibration" or "taring" of the results against the controls (baseline) is appropriate; it is domain specific, and you will need to justify it. And similarly, depending on what you know of the hormone's function, a ratio (multiplicative effect) or subtraction (additive effect) may be the more appropriate "calibration".
Note that you could also ratio (or subtract) the average control signal per run from the replicates for the corresponding run, and then do a 2-sample t comparing control to treatment. But, the average ratio (diff) for the controls of each run will be 1 (0), and thus does not add any info, but you now have to use a 2-sample t with additional variability, which loses some power.
Fwiw, I tried all 4 (ratios or differences, 1-sample or 2-sample t) and I got similar, and (very?) significant results (p<.004), with ratios and the 1 sample t giving lower p values.

Hi @jginestet, thank you for your answer and suggestions. A simple 1/2-sample t-test seems like it could solve my issue, but I'm a bit anxious about using all within-run replicates as individual values as well, because the measurements will also depend on the plant leaf they originated from. Shouldn't that be taken into consideration? I do feel I would be getting into regression/mixed model territory then, which I am very unfamiliar with... what do you think?

Why not use the within run replicates as individual values; they are after all from different leaves; they are separate "units" (i.e. they are not replicated measurements of the same leaf). So they are independent measurements, under similar conditions (because from the same run). So use them for higher statistical power. Wrt regression, with only 1 binary factor (control vs. treatment), you can show that a 2-sample t-test is in fact a linear regression (and vice-versa); you will get the same exact p-value... And 2-sample test is redundant, as the mean of the controls is 1 by construction...
